# How to get a one-shot message with MQTT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, mqtt

I wrote a monitoring service for my home automation system. One of the things I would like to monitor are Zigbee devices, controlled by [Zigbee2MQTT](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/).

I need to retrieve from Zigbee2MQTT the configured devices and perform some checks. Ideally there would be a synchronous API in Zigbee2MQTT to get this information, but it is all MQTT-based:
- I need to subscribe to a topic
- send a message to another topic
- and I will the receive on the first topic the configuration.

My first question would be: is there a ready-made solution for such one-shot cases? Something along the lines of

```
response_payload = client.one_shot(response_topic, probe_topic, timeout)
```

I believe there is none, so I tried to wrote my own. The code below does not work, probably because I never used a threaded MQTT connection (it was always an infinite loop, and such cases worked fine) and do not properly understand how to use it:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

class GetConfig:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = None
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        # the connection is threaded so that a timeout check on the (lack of) answer can be done
        self.client.connect_async("mqtt.example.com")
        self.client.loop_start()
        # wait 5 seconds, then fail <-- there was no configuration retrieved
        for _ in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
        self.client.loop_stop()
        self.client.disconnect()
        raise ValueError('did not get config on time')

    def on_connect(self):
        self.client.subscribe('zigbee2mqtt/bridge/config/devices')
        self.client.publish('zigbee2mqtt/bridge/config/devices/get')

    def on_message(self):
        # we received an answer, the payload will be handled here, then close successfully
        print("received message, closing")
        self.client.loop_stop()
        self.client.disconnect()

GetConfig()
```

I always get the `ValueError` exception (= no response after 5 seconds) and it seems that the `on_connect` method is never reached. Why?

Comment: You are not actually publishing anything on the get topic.

Comment: @hardillb: I am publishing an empty message (https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#publishing), but even adding an explicit `payload=""` does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signatures on your callback's are wrong.

(Also you have no success path, so it will always say it failed.)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

class GetConfig:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = None
        self.got_config = False
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.connect_async("mqtt.example.com")
        self.client.loop_start()
        for _ in range(5):
            if self.got_config:
                self.disconnect()
                return
            time.sleep(1)
        self.disconnect()
        raise ValueError('did not get config on time')

    def disconnect(self):
        self.client.loop_stop()
        self.client.disconnect()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        self.client.subscribe('zigbee2mqtt/bridge/config/devices')
        self.client.publish('zigbee2mqtt/bridge/config/devices/get')

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        print(f"received message, closing: {message.payload}")
        self.got_config = True
        self.disconnect()

GetConfig()
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot the parameters. It now works great. I took the liberty to update your code with a version which indeed has a success exit path. Thanks again!